# Different output with string and char array

Tags: c++

When I am using the following code to convert an string to a float, it is working fine. But the next code gives the error. Please tell me why is this happening? String is a char array only is what I read.

Code1 (working)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[]="301.23";
    float f=atof(str);
    cout<<sizeof(str)<<" is size with contents "<<str<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(f)<<" is size with contents "<<f<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Code 2(not working)

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="301.23";
    float f=atof(str);
    cout<<sizeof(str)<<" is size with contents "<<str<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(f)<<" is size with contents "<<f<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
 error: cannot convert std::string to const char* for argument 1 to double atof(const char*)
```

Please help

Comment: Use `cstring` and `cstdlib`.

Comment: I really think you need to learn the language first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double atof( const char *str );
```

The input string is a sequence of characters that can be interpreted as a numeric value of the specified return type.

The function stops reading the input string at the first character that it cannot recognize as part of a number. This character can be the null character that ends the string.

The atof() function expects a string in the following form:

```
     Read syntax diagramSkip visual syntax diagram
>>-+------------+--+-----+--+-digits--+---+--+--------+-+------->
       '-whitespace-'  +- + -+  |         '-.-'  '-digits-' |
                       '- – -'  '-.--digits-----------------'
```

Therefore your problem lies in the atof funcion which is not designed to accept string at it doesn't store characters in integer form.

Hope this helped.. :D

Answer (score 7):

`std::string` is not a char array.
Use `str.c_str()` to get a `const char*` and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try using `#include<cstring>` in place of `#include <string>`
Technically, You're only guaranteed std::string, but all popular implementations just pull in the C header and add a using statement...
 is a C++ standard library include, and  is C standard library include.

Comment: Problem is OP doesn't know difference between `string` and `char []`.